# Can any cloud functions have a UK IP address?

Tags: mongodb, azure, aws-lambda, google-cloud-functions

I'm looking at creating a mobile application that will need to connect with a third-party API. This API requires a UK IP address, so I need cloud functions with a UK IP address.

Google Cloud Functions don't seem to support this. I think AWS may do, but I don't really understand any of it enough just yet (a GCP man). Asked MongoDB support but they directed me to a ticket system and no reply yet.

It would be great if someone could point me to a provider that supports cloud functions with UK IP addresses and an guide on how to set it up.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam

Comment: Not a recommendation, I'm asking which providers offer a specific service and how to implement it. Nothing to be opinionated about.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad

Comment: "They are open-ended; there is never one perfect answer to them". There's multiple upvoted answers on almost all questions, meaning "not one perfect answer to them". Perfectly legitimate to ask where I can find cloud functions that enable UK IP addresses without causing a frenzy.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy your `Cloud Function` in different regions in the world. To see all the available regions you can go to [Cloud locations - Products available by region](https://cloud.google.com/about/locations/?region=americas#products-available-by-region) documentation. Cloud Functions are not available in all the regions as you can see from the documentation and the United Kingdom is not listed in the available regions.

Therefore, it is not possible to have a Cloud Function running on UK ip. As a workaround you can always redirect the request using another API.